# Sudden battery drain on Samsung Galaxy Ace 2x

Tags: battery-life

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace 2x that is not yet a year old.  For the last 6 weeks, the battery has been draining very quickly, even though I have turned off everything that would cause this (GPS, WiFi, Bluetooth, etc.) I have an unlimited mobile browser, and since this started to happen, I have noticed that my data consumption has jumped considerably even though I am doing nothing different (normal usage was between 500-700 mB per month, now 3-4 gB per month). For some reason it seems that the data is constantly on, or the phone is searching for a network, even when I am not using it. I have to charge the phone at least twice a day.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Go to settings > Battery

There you can see the list of things that consume battery. This includes all the system processes, hardware such as the screen and the user apps.
If there is an application that you installed that takes up more than say 20% in that list, that app is your culprit. There is also a good chance that it is the same app that is taking up all that data in the backgrounds. If your screen takes up more than 30%, try reducing your brightness and the amount of time the screen is kept active.

If you want to check your mobile data consumption, 
Go to Settings > Data usage.
This will list the data consumption of all apps on the phone.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I hava a Samsung S5. Before I charged my phone once per 24 or 48 hours and since a few days suddently the battery lasted only 4 to 8 hours. After several test I discovered the cause was a few corrupt images. I deleted the corrupt images and the problem was solved. I used [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tostis.corruptimagefinder) to find the corrupt images.